# Merge xml files and delete duplicates when certain line field value already exists

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have two XML files of the same structure, each with over 100,000 entries and would like to merge them. File1 shall be my source file and I only would like to add entries from File2 when the value of field VATRegistrationNumber does not already exists in File1.
Lines with an empty VATRegistrationNumber still need to be added to the output file.
I'm after a resourceful solution that does not use a lot of memory as I would need to run the merger on a daily basis in a Windows task scheduler. So I was thinking either XSLT, powershell or batch.

File1:

```
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008755" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PETER GOW" City="LISMORE" VATRegistrationNumber="60185579027" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008754" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="DANIEL PETRUSHNKO" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="52216736429" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008753" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PEOPLE2PEOPLE" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008752" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PEARL CLEANING" City="WOONONA" VATRegistrationNumber="29169648828" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008751" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PATTO'S PAINTLESS" City="TAMWORTH" VATRegistrationNumber="30482156828" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008750" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PATRICK ST CLINIC" City="PENGUIN" VATRegistrationNumber="53220182389"  />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008749" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="MITCHELL PAISH" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="42091590585" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008748" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PACNET INTERNET" City="MELBOURNE" VATRegistrationNumber="69085213690" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008747" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="NICHOLAS J OWENS" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="32168537004" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008746" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="JOHN O'SULLIVAN" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="51136629180" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008745" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="OSTAR ELECTRICAL" City="BANGALOW" VATRegistrationNumber="47196051022" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008756" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PKL COURIERS" City="PALM BEACH" VATRegistrationNumber="90690407812" />
```

File2:

```
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008788" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="MICHAEL JOHN MCMANUS" City="COBAR" VATRegistrationNumber="51136629180" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008787" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="MOREE PROPERTY" City="MOREE" VATRegistrationNumber="52216736429" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008786" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="PATRICIA GOULD" City="MUDGEE" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008785" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="KAREN DRUCE" City="Warrimoo" VATRegistrationNumber="42091590585" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008784" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="SOLAR SOLUTIONS" City="MUDGEE" VATRegistrationNumber="65164304054" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008783" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="ST GEORGES CHURCH" City="Hurstville" VATRegistrationNumber="79115673239" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008782" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="SHARED VALUE" City="PORT MELBOURNE" VATRegistrationNumber="32168537004" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008781" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="ALLEN KIRK" City="STUARTS POINT" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008775" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="NATIONAL REMOVALS" City="ASHMORE" VATRegistrationNumber="19748626605" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008774" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="INLAND CONTAINER" City="DUBBO" VATRegistrationNumber="78001638777" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008814" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="CTARS PTY LTD" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="59603816593" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008813" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="JENNY &amp; MARSH" City="LAMBTON" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008812" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="ACDMA CENTRE" City="Canley Vale" VATRegistrationNumber="58002378731" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008999" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="CENTRAL HOTEL" City="Sydney" VATRegistrationNumber="47196051022" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008969" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="ALES LICHNER" City="BANGOR" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
```

Expected Output file:

```
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008755" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PETER GOW" City="LISMORE" VATRegistrationNumber="60185579027" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008754" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="DANIEL PETRUSHNKO" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="52216736429" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008753" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PEOPLE2PEOPLE" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008752" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PEARL CLEANING" City="WOONONA" VATRegistrationNumber="29169648828" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008751" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PATTO'S PAINTLESS" City="TAMWORTH" VATRegistrationNumber="30482156828" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008750" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PATRICK ST CLINIC" City="PENGUIN" VATRegistrationNumber="53220182389"  />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008749" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="MITCHELL PAISH" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="42091590585" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008748" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PACNET INTERNET" City="MELBOURNE" VATRegistrationNumber="69085213690" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008747" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="NICHOLAS J OWENS" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="32168537004" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008746" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="JOHN O'SULLIVAN" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="51136629180" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008745" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="OSTAR ELECTRICAL" City="BANGALOW" VATRegistrationNumber="47196051022" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="300008756" CorporateGroupID="1000" Name1="PKL COURIERS" City="PALM BEACH" VATRegistrationNumber="90690407812" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008786" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="PATRICIA GOULD" City="MUDGEE" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008784" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="SOLAR SOLUTIONS" City="MUDGEE" VATRegistrationNumber="65164304054" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008783" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="ST GEORGES CHURCH" City="Hurstville" VATRegistrationNumber="79115673239" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008781" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="ALLEN KIRK" City="STUARTS POINT" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008775" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="NATIONAL REMOVALS" City="ASHMORE" VATRegistrationNumber="19748626605" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008774" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="INLAND CONTAINER" City="DUBBO" VATRegistrationNumber="78001638777" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008814" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="CTARS PTY LTD" City="SYDNEY" VATRegistrationNumber="59603816593" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008813" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="JENNY &amp; MARSH" City="LAMBTON" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008812" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="ACDMA CENTRE" City="Canley Vale" VATRegistrationNumber="58002378731" />
  <Supplier SupplierNumber="9008969" CorporateGroupID="2000" Name1="ALES LICHNER" City="BANGOR" VATRegistrationNumber="" />
```

I have worked on a solution with Powershell as it is easier for me to understand and I have so far gotten to the the point of merging the two files using the below powershell code:

```
[xml]$File1 = Get-Content file1.xml
[xml]$File2 = Get-Content file2.xml
ForEach ($XmlNode in $File2.DocumentElement.ChildNodes){$File1.DocumentElement.AppendChild($File1.ImportNode($XmlNode, $true))}
$File1.Save('file1and2combined.xml')
```

In a second step I was able to clean up the combined file by only keeping entries with a unique VAT Registration number and writing the result into another file using code:

```
[xml]$myfile = [xml](Get-content "file1and2combined.xml")
$nodesToRemove = $myfile.suppliers.childnodes | Group-Object VATRegistrationNumber |
    Foreach-Object { $_.Group | Select-Object -Skip 1 }
    
$nodesToRemove | Foreach-Object {
    $myfile.suppliers.RemoveChild($_)
}
#save XML
$myfile.Save("file1and2cleaned_result.xml")
```

But now I'm stuck and I need some assistance. At the moment nodes with an empty VAT Registration Number are getting dropped as well but I need to keep those.

Comment: For sequential processing, it would help if these files were sorted by the VAT registration number. Is it feasible to have the input files sorted in that way?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The files don't come sorted by VAT registration number but can be sorted prior to be processed as long as the structure and the order of the fields stays the same. However, I wouldn't know how to do this.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I'm a complete newbie to XSLT and have had some success with PowerShell but it takes an awful long time to process those huge files. Would you be able to provide more assistance on how exactly I would go about it with XSLT. Just wondering if this would be a more resourceful solution although I have no idea how this will work once I have a complete XSLT script which would resolves my problem.

Comment: Have you considered my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72517145/16462950)?

Answer (score 0):

@jana I have some similar situations, with rather large files, and the solution I came up with is to create two arrays of the VATRegistration numbers, Then you can quickly loop through the second array, testing for each VAT# in the first array, and import the Supplier element if not found. You minimize XML work by doing your decision making with simple arrays. The issue becomes, do you have duplicates in the files now, and what do you do with elements with a blank VAT#, which I see does occur.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal that leaves the efficient lookup of VAT registration numbers to the XSLT processor.

Let the XSL transformation declare a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key) and two variables for the two files:

```xml
<xsl:key name="vat" match="Supplier[@VATRegistrationNumber!='']" use="@VATRegistrationNumber"/>
<xsl:variable name="file1" select="document('file1')"/>
<xsl:variable name="file2" select="document('file2')"/>
```

The condition in the `match` ensures that a `Supplier` with empty `VATRegistrationNumber` has no key.

Then the desired `Supplier`s can be output with the following statements:

```xml
<xsl:copy-of select="$file1//Supplier"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$file2//Supplier">
  <!-- Do not output this Supplier if its key exists in $file1. -->
  <xsl:if test="$file1[not(key('vat',current()/@VATRegistrationNumber))]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The `key` condition is enclosed in `$file1[...]` in order to switch the context node to file 1, because that is the context in which the key is determined.